# Proving the properties of kernels in cosmological non-linear perturbation theory

Tags: cosmology

In non-linear cosmological perturbation theory, one can compute loop corrections to the linear matter power spectrum which are necessary to accurately describe the statistics of matter at quasi-linear scales. In the Standard Perturbation Theory (SPT) approach, these loop corrections are generally UV divergent. The terms contributing to the one-loop matter power spectrum are given in Eqs. (7.133) & (7.136) of [this reference](https://academic.oup.com/book/44246#:%7E:text=Effective%20field%20theory%20(EFT)%20is,scales%20in%20a%20tractable%20fashion.). I'm trying to compute the leading UV terms of these integrals as given in Eqs. (7.140) & (7.142). To do this, one needs to take the UV ($q \rightarrow \infty$) limit of the perturbation theory kernels $F_n$ which satisfy the properties given in Eqs. (7.127, 7.128) or the three numbered points near Eq. (2.11) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9509047.pdf).

I need help proving the property involving the UV limit of the kernels. Here's the [Mathematica code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16EQ4pnkHjRoNF9VTDYmGE_0Y06e-NrAL/view?usp=sharing) that I'm using. It would also be great if you help reproduce Eqs. (7.140) & (7.142) with exact numerical factors! :'-)

Answer (score 0):

First lets collect some equations. We have
$$P_{22}(k) = 2 \int \frac{d^3 q} {(2\pi)^3} P(q) P(|\mathbf{k}  -\mathbf{q}  |)|F_2(\mathbf{q}  ,\mathbf{k}  -\mathbf{q}  )|^2\tag{7.133}$$
$$P_{13}=3 P_{{\rm lin} }(k)\int \frac{d^3 q} {(2\pi)^3} P_{\rm lin} (q)F_3(\mathbf{k}  ,\mathbf{q}  ,-\mathbf{q}  )\tag{7.136}$$
And using these we want to show that
$$P_{22}(k)\xrightarrow{k\ll q} \frac{9}{98}k^4 \int \frac{d^3 q} {(2\pi)^3} \frac{P^2(q)} {q^4} \tag{7.140}$$
$$P_{13}(k) \xrightarrow{k\ll q} -\frac{1}{3}k^2 P(k) \int \frac{d^3 q} {(2\pi)^3} \frac{P(q)} {q^2} \left( \frac{61} {210} - \frac{2}{35} \frac{k^2}{q^2}+\dots \right) \tag{7.142}$$
As discussed below Eq. (7.133) of Baldauf's notes, to explicitly evaluate $P_{22}$ and $P_{13}$ it is convenient to parameterize the momenta as
$$\mathbf{k}  =(0,0,k)\tag{A}$$
$$\mathbf{q}  = rk\biggr(\sqrt{ 1-\mu^2 } ,0, \mu\biggr)\tag{B}$$
Note that we can relate $\mu,r$ to $q,k$
$$q^2 = r^2 k^2(1-\mu^2 + \mu^2)\Rightarrow \underline{r = \frac{q}{k}}$$
$$\begin{align} 
kq\cos\theta &= \mathbf{k}  \cdot \mathbf{q}  =rk^2 \mu = kq\mu\Rightarrow \underline{\mu = \cos\theta}
\end{align} $$

---

## The low-$k$ limit of $P_{22}(k)$

In the parameterization spelled out in Eqs. (A,B), Eq. (7.133) turns into Eq.(7.134)
$$P_{22}(k) = \frac{k^3} {2\pi^2} \int dr\ r^2\int d\mu\ P(rk)P(\psi(r,\mu)k) |F_{2,d}(r,\mu)|^2\tag{7.134}$$
where
$$\psi(r,\mu) = \sqrt{ 1+r^2 - 2 r \mu } $$
$$F_{2,d}(r,\mu) = \frac{7\mu+(3-10\mu^2)r} {14 r(r^2 -2\mu r + 1)} \tag{7.135}$$
Now note that the low-$k$ limit corresponds to $r\rightarrow \infty$. So you can compute[1] that
$$|F_{2,d}(r,\mu)|^2= \frac{(3-10\mu^2)^2} {196 r^4} +O(r^{-5})$$
Also note that $\psi(r,\mu)k\xrightarrow{k\ll q}rk$. Thus Eq. (7.134) turns into
$$P_{22}(k) \xrightarrow{k\ll q} \frac{k^3} {2\pi^2} \int dr\ \frac{P(rk)^2}{196 r^2}\int d\mu \ (3-10\mu^2)^2$$
Since $\mu=\cos\theta$ and the angle between $\mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ could be anything, the inner integral goes between $[-1, 1]$:
$$\int_{-1}^1 d\mu\ (3-10\mu^2)^2 = 18$$
This gives us the result
$$\boxed{P_{22}(k) \xrightarrow{k\ll q} \frac{9} {98} \times \frac{k^3} {2\pi^2} \int dr\ \frac{P(rk)^2} {r^2}}$$
You can show that this is equivalent to Eq. (7.140) as follows. First for our result above we change variables from $r$ back to $q$:
$$P_{22}(k)\xrightarrow{k\ll q}\frac 9 {98}\times \frac{k^4} {2\pi^2} \int {dq} \frac{P(q)^2} {q^2} $$
and this is equivalent to Eq. (7.140) once you go from $\int d^3 q \rightarrow \int q^2 dq\int d^2\Omega$.

## The low-$k$ limit of $P_{13}(k)$

Similar business as before. The parameterizaiton Eqs. (A,B) leads to Eq. (7.137) in Baldauf's notes:
$$\begin{align} 
P_{13}(k) &= \frac{k^3} {{\color{red}2\times }252(2\pi)^2} P(k) \int dr\ r^2 P(kr)\times\\
&\times \left[ \frac{12}{r^4}- \frac{158}{r^2}+100 - 42 r^2 + \frac{3}{r^5}(7r^2 + 2) (r^2-1)^3\log \left( \frac{r+1} {r-1}  \right) \right]
\end{align} \tag{7.137}$$
In red I have added an additional factor of $1 / 2$ which I believe to be a typo in the notes[2]

Again we can run to Mathematica and expand the argument of the integral for $r\rightarrow\infty\Leftrightarrow k\ll q$.
$$P_{13}(k)\xrightarrow{k\ll q} \frac{k^3}{2\times252 (2\pi)^2}P(k)\times \frac{1008}{3}\int dr\ P(kr) \left[ -\frac{61}{210}+ \frac{2}{35 r^2}- \frac{10}{441 r^4}+\dots \right]$$
Where I've chosen the numerical prefactor to make the terms inside the square brackets match what Tobias has. To clean things up a bit lets change variables from $r$ to $q$ like before:
$$\boxed{P_{13}(k)\xrightarrow{k\ll q} -\frac{1}{3}{k^2}  P(k)\int \frac{dq}{2\pi^2}\ P(q) \left[ \frac{61}{210}-\frac{2}{35} \frac{k^2}{q^2}+\dots \right]}$$
And again, this is equivalent to Eq. (7.142) once you go from $\int d^3 q\rightarrow \int q^2dq\int d^2\Omega$

[1]: In Mathematica something like `Series[F2d^2,{r,\infty,4}]`

[2]:For example compare Eqs. (7.132) and (7.136) to Eqs. (2.5) and (2.7) of [1301.7182](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7182.pdf) by Pajer and Zaldarriaga. The definitions of $P_{13}$ in Eq. (2.5) and Eq. (7.132) differ by a factor of $2$ yet Eq (7.136) and Eq. (2.7) are the same.